Using wifi causes SPI display to stop functioning on Xiao ESP32c3 with GC9A01 display
I'm trying to display graphics using tft_espi while doing wifi stuff, but it seems that turning on the wifi module causes display updates to cease working. I've tried rewriting the code using FreeRTOS and arduino, no dice. It seems like you can turn on WiFi and keep it on while displaying stuff no problem, but turning on WiFi breaks things. Any tips would be appreciated. Sister post on the Seeed Studio (manufacturers of the device and display): https://forum.seeedstudio.com/t/xiao-esp32c3-with-round-display-touch-not-working-with-wifi/283388/11
Edit: I've written a much simpler application that shows the fault. There is a simple animation in the center, and two buttons to change the color of the animation. After 10 cycles of the animation, I turn on WiFi and try to connect, and everything freezes:
#include <SPI.h>
#include <TFT_eSPI.h>
#include "I2C_BM8563.h"
#define USE_TFT_ESPI_LIBRARY
#include "lv_xiao_round_screen.h"

#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

TFT_eSprite img = TFT_eSprite(&tft);

const char *ssid = "ST";
const char *password = "test1234";


// https://rgbcolorpicker.com/565
#define WHITE 0xFFFF
#define BLACK 0x0000
#define BLUE 0x001F
#define RED 0xF800
#define GREEN 0x07E0

double center_x = 120;
double center_y = 120;

lv_coord_t touchX, touchY;

bool init_wifi = false;
bool connected_wifi = false;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Start I2C
  Wire.begin();

  WiFi.disconnect();
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);
  // WiFi.enableSTA(true);

  tft.begin();
  tft.setRotation(0);
  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);

  static lv_indev_drv_t indev_drv;
  lv_indev_drv_init(&indev_drv);
  indev_drv.type = LV_INDEV_TYPE_POINTER;
  indev_drv.read_cb = chsc6x_read;
  lv_indev_drv_register(&indev_drv);

  img.setColorDepth(16);
}

int rad = 0;
uint32_t color = GREEN;
int cnt = 0;

void loop() {

  // Process button inputs to color animation
  if (chsc6x_is_pressed()) {
    chsc6x_get_xy(&touchX, &touchY);
    if (touchX > center_x) {
      color = RED;
    } else {
      color = GREEN;
    }
  }

  // Drive the animation
  int rad = cnt % 40;

  // Draw some buttons and a simple animation
  img.createSprite(240, 240);
  img.fillScreen(BLACK);
  img.drawCircle(center_x, center_y, 40, WHITE);
  img.drawCircle(center_x, center_y, rad, color);
  img.fillCircle(center_x + 80, center_y, 10, RED);
  img.fillCircle(center_x - 80, center_y, 10, GREEN);
  img.fillCircle(center_x, center_y - 80, 10, init_wifi ? connected_wifi ? GREEN : BLUE : BLACK);
  img.pushSprite(0, 0, TFT_TRANSPARENT);
  img.deleteSprite();

  // Enable wifi after 400 cnts have passed
  if (cnt > 400)
  {
    // On first loop initialize wifi
    if (!init_wifi) {
      WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
      WiFi.enableSTA(true);
      WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
      init_wifi = true;
    }

    // On every subsequent loop, check connection status
    if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
      connected_wifi = true;
    }
  } 

  cnt++;
}


Reduce the code to the minimum required and kick out the delays, then come back here with a precise description what is not working.

Almost every problem I ever had with FreeRTOS came down to interrupt priorities. But I've never programmed for ESP32.

"_ It seems like you can turn on WiFi and keep it on while displaying stuff no problem, but turning on WiFi breaks things._", so when WiFi is on, it is both fine and it breaks?!  Some clarity required here.  Since the code is clearly Arduino, mentioning FreeRTOS is irrelevant.

Line 152 of your posted code is an opening {.  You need to be clearer about what line you are referring to.

Sorry for the confusion. I'm writing a simpler example app that has the same problem and will post in a moment. The esp32 board's arduino code is based on FreeRTOS. You can generate tasks and just kill the setup and loop tasks (making it less like standard arduino). I just mentioned it because its something I tried, but I don't think it had an effect.

I've edited the post with a much simpler example that shows the problem.

How much memory you have when uploading the code? You have several memory-hungry libraries. Each sprite would require 2 x ScreenWide x SceenHeight memory for 16-bit color depth(i.e. 2 x 240 x 240 = 115200 bytes in your case). WiFi would require more for its 16-ch buffer. Also add Serial.println(ESP.getFreeHeap()); in your loop to check if there is any memory leak.

Please also add the relevant debug output from ESP-s serial port. Check that your WiFi is on 2.4GHz, 5GHz is not supported by ESP.

I'm using a phone hotspot to run the wifi. It's 2.4 and 5 GHz, and I've connected to it with the esp32c3 successfully.  There is no debug output from the ESP unless I add serial prints, which show that execution is continuing as normal.
As for memory, this is what arduino outputs:
Wrote 1034752 bytes (640236 compressed) at 0x00010000 in 7.8 seconds (effective 1057.2 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.

Leaving...
Hard resetting via RTS pin...

It looks like the project takes 0.6 MB, which seems reasonable.

You are talking about the compiled code size, which is the flash memory. I'm asking about the dynamic memory during execution, that is, the RAM, for the screen buffer and others. The reason is if you are running out of memory (RAM), it will crash (which will throw exception) or frozen(without telling you anything).

I have no idea what the cnt for and why you need to initial the wifi in a loop instead of in the setup(). So one question for you is what happens if cnt is overflow that it reach the max and reset to 0? For Arduino, and int is not a big number, it is between -32768 to +32767.

The datasheet says that the chip only has 400 KiB of (S)RAM. You're allocating 115 KB on every execution of loop(), so any segmentation in the memory can cause the allocation to fail. Running out of RAM is also a real possibility. Please verify that the loop() function continues to be called and that createSprite() returns a non-null value after WiFi initialization.
